# [ROS2 FOXY] : Could not transform base_link to map because "map" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist

Tags: ros, ros2, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello , i am trying to do the transform between 2 frames (base_link and map) using the tf2_ros package, but it seems there is an issue somewhere.
Both of the frames (base_link and map) do exist , i can see it on the tree frames when i use tf2_tools view_frames.py , also i am able to do the transform when using tf2_ros tf2_echo between my 2 frames and even more relevant , i am able to see on rviz all of the tfs being placed right, but when i am using in my code the lookup_transfrom method to get the transform between base_link and map, it says "Could not transform XPal_2/base_link to map because "map" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist".
here is the relevant code (knowing all of this code is inside a ros node called "SlamLocalization") :

```
self.source_frame = config_server.ROBOT_NETWORK["namespace"] + "/" + "base_link"   #namespace is XPal_2
self.target_frame = "map"

self.slam_tf_buffer = Buffer()
self.slam_tf_subscriber = TransformListener(self.slam_tf_buffer, self)
self.timer = self.create_timer(0.05, self.slam_tf_callback)

def slam_tf_callback(self):
       """
       Callback function for slam tf subscriber between map and robot frames
       """
       try:
           slam_tf = self.slam_tf_buffer.lookup_transform(self.target_frame, self.source_frame, rclpy.time.Time(),rclpy.duration.Duration(seconds=4.0) )
           logger.log("tf_transform : {}".format(slam_tf))
       except TransformException as ex:
           logger.log('Could not transform {} to {} because {}'.format(self.source_frame, self.target_frame, ex))
           return

       self.publish_slam_position(slam_tf) #method used to publish on a topic the position , not relevant for this issue

def main(args=None):
   rclpy.init(args=args)

   slam_localization = SlamLocalization()

   executor = MultiThreadedExecutor()

   rclpy.spin(slam_localization, executor=executor)

   # Destroy the node explicitly
   slam_localization.destroy_node()
   rclpy.shutdown()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Also important to know , the frames map and odom (which is the child of map) are published by the package slam_toolbox and the rest of the frames are published by the urdf file (base_link and all of his childs)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415719/%5Bros2-foxy%5D-:-could-not-transform-base_link-to-map-because-%22map%22-passed-to-lookuptransform-argument-target_frame-does-not-exist./) by [Rstef](https://answers.ros.org/users/150846/rstef/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2023-05-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2023-05-23**:
Does it error once or a couple of times at startup? Or does it continuously happen?

**Comment by [Rstef](https://answers.ros.org/users/150846/rstef/) on 2023-05-24**:
the error happens continuously

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2023-05-24**:
That probably means that you aren't receiving any data. You should check what the SlamLocalization is doing in the spin. Is rclpy turning over and receiving any messages?

**Comment by [Rstef](https://answers.ros.org/users/150846/rstef/) on 2023-05-25**:
The node is spinning right and it is receiving all the messages needed , here is what the ros node info returns :

```
/XPal_2/slam_localization
Subscribers:
/XPal_2/tf: tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage
/XPal_2/tf_static: tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage
Publishers:
/XPal_2/slam_position: ea_custom_message/msg/MsgPosition
/parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
/rosout: rcl_interfaces/msg/Log
Service Servers:
/XPal_2/slam_localization/describe_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/DescribeParameters
/XPal_2/slam_localization/get_parameter_types: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameterTypes
/XPal_2/slam_localization/get_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameters
/XPal_2/slam_localization/list_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/ListParameters
/XPal_2/slam_localization/set_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters
/XPal_2/slam_localization/set_parameters_atomically: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParametersAtomically
```

tell me if you need more informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK i found out where my issue was , after i looked at the info of the node "slam_localization" i noticed that the 2 subscribers created by the transform listener were subscribing to the wrong topic , indeed , they are subscribing to the topic /XPal_2/tf and /XPal_2/tf_static although the topics where the tf are being published are just /tf and /tf_static , so that means either my nodes which are publishing the tf on the topics are missing the namespace either i need to remove the namespace on the node "slam_localization".
Anyway i found a work aroud method which is to subscribe / publish the info between the topics /tf , /tf_static and /XPal_2/tf and /XPal_2/tf_static.
Hope that helps if anyone is having the same issue.

---

Originally posted by [Rstef](https://answers.ros.org/users/150846/rstef/) with karma: 21 on 2023-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1